# sensitive data leakage from -- response.getWriter().write(xml.toString()); via web page

Tags: java, stringbuffer, sensitive-data

```
xml.append("<alertDesc>");
xml.append(desc);
xml.append("</alertDesc>");

response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());  
response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

`xml` is a `StringBuffer` object.

I have this piece of code and there is some leakage of sensitive data from the syntax     `response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());`. I don't have any idea of this thing.

Can any one tell me something about this? This issue is been reported by a code audit tool.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?

Comment: keep that line at the end after you set contentType and header and Let us know

Comment: no changing the order of the syntax does not have any effect on the issue..... n how you projected that to be a solution to the problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use validator and escaping techniches from ESAPI to wrap the desc field It will help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its a wild guess, but did you forget to close a variable?